# Should I escape and sanitize data from facebook connect?

Tags: php, security, facebook

I'm using the facebook php sdk for a facebook app.

How safe is the `$me = $facebook->api('/me')` object? should I escape and sanitize the 'name' and 'id' I get before querying the database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is probably always a good idea to sanitize input from external systems that are not under your control. I would definitely do it.

Comment: To be clear, it is always required to sanitize data before use it in the query. And doesn't matter where you got that data. It even can be fetched from your database in previous lines.

Comment: Never trust anything from any external source. Who knows what it will send you.